# Problems with 'int'

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, user-input

I'm new to programming, so I want to write a code that will let me input a 2 dimensional array (or a matrix in my case) and print it afterwards.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printArray( const int *array, int count ) 
    { 
       for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) 
          cout << array[ i ] << " "; 

       cout << endl; 
    }

int main () {
int n;
cout<<"Please enter the length of your matrix : "<<endl;
cin>>n;
int * y=new int [n];
for (int w = 0; w <= n-1; w++ ) {

    y[w] = new int [n];
    cout<<"Insert the elements ";

            for (int z = 0; z <= n-1; z++)
            {
                cin >>y [w][z];
            }   
}

printArray(y, n);

}
```

However I get errors like "invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'" and "invalid types int[int] for array subscript". Can you please review my code and point my flaws?

Thanks

Comment: @RyanGray if the array isn't fixed size (which it isn't) then it has to be newed. Of course, one should really use structures such as `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @RyanGray: using `new[]` is a legitimate way to create an array, and it is not the same as `new`.

Comment: you need to use double pointers, your array y needs to be declared int ** y = new int* [n]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared `y` as an `int*` which would only be 1-dimensional. You would need to declare `y` as `int**` for it to be 2-dimensional.

The reason your code does not compile is because `int* y` points to a *single* block of memory (that being an array of integers, in other words, a bunch of `int`s.). `y[w]` is one of those `int`s inside this array so `y[w] = new int[n]` fails to compile because you are trying to assign an `int*` to an `int`.

**Changing `y` to an `int**` means that `y` can point to an array of `int*`s. Since each `int*` can point to an array of `int`, you will have a 2-dimensional array.**

Example code for 10x10 matrix with `int**`:

```
int** iShouldUseStdVector = new int*[10]; // allocate 10 int* <--
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    iShouldUseStdVector[i] = new int[10]; // allocate 10 int <--
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        iShouldUseStdVector[i][k] = k;
    }
}
```

Example code for 10x10 matrix with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> thisIsEasy;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    thisIsEasy.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        thisIsEasy[i].push_back(k);
    }
}
```

---

I would recommend using `std::vector<std::vector<int>> y;` instead since it handles the memory for you by conveniently growing as you want to add more elements and freeing the memory when its destructed.

Answer (score 1):

> int * y=new int [n];

That is an array of length `n`. What you would need is:

```
int **y = new int*[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    y[i] = new int[n];

....

//delete[] y[i] in a loop
delete[] y;
```

Since you are using C++, why not:

```
#include <vector>

...
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int * y=new int [n];` is a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array of `int` values;

`y[w] = new int [n];` tries to assign a pointer into an element of the array.

As a learning exercise, messing around with raw arrays is a good idea.  Once you know how to use them, you will know enough to stop using them (very much) and go with automatic storage types like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You want to declare `y` as a pointer to an array of `int`:

```
int ** y = new int* [n];
```

2) In `printArray` you are dealing with a matrix, not an array. To access the members of a matrix use two nested `for` loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nLines; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < nColumns; j++) {
        std::cout << matrix[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

3) You need to pass a pointer to an array of `int`, not a pointer to an `int` to the `printArray` method.

```
void printArray( const int **array, int count )
```

---

Find the working code, with the above fixes here: http://ideone.com/2h9dR

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate the link.

Answer (score 0):

First, read the other answers and then perhaps reread the pointer chapter in a good C++ book. Now, unless you need extreme speeds, use `vector` of `vector` of `double`. With C++11 (the newer C++ standard) it's really nice and readable, so I post that first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printArray( std::vector< std::vector<double> > & v ) {
   for ( const auto & row : v ){
      for ( const auto & value : row ){
        std::cout << value << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

int main () {
   int n;
   std::cout<<"Please enter the length of your matrix : "<<std::endl;
   std::cin>>n;
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> y(n,std::vector<double>(n,0));
   for ( auto & row : y ){
      std::cout<<"Insert the elements of row :";
      for ( auto & value : row ){
        std::cin >> value;
      }   
   }
   printArray(y);   
}
```

For older C++ it's like this:

```
void printArray( std::vector< std::vector<double> > & v ) {
   for ( std::vector<std::vector<double> >::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end();it++){
      for ( std::vector<double>::const_iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2!= it->end();it2++) {
     std::cout << (*it2) << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

int main () {
   int n;
   std::cout<<"Please enter the length of your matrix : "<<std::endl;
   std::cin>>n;
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > y(n,std::vector<double>(n,0));
   for ( std::vector<std::vector<double> >::iterator it = y.begin(); it!= y.end();it++){
      std::cout<<"Insert the elements of row :";
      for ( std::vector<double>::iterator it2 = it->begin(); it2!= it->end();it2++) {
     std::cin >> (*it2);
      }   
   }
   printArray(y);   
}
```

Note that `y(n,std::vector<double>(n,0))` means to make `n` vectors, each with `n` zeros. You can use also use `y[1][2]` to get and set values. If you use y.at(1).at(2) instead you get proper checking so that you get an exception if you read or write out of bounds.