# Inputing the Size of a 2-dimentional Array

Tags: c++, arrays, size

In my code I input the sizes of both dimensions and then declare a two-dimensional array. My question is, how do I use that array as a function parameter? I know that I need to write the number of columns in the function specification but how do I pass the number of columns?

```
 void gameDisplay(gameCell p[][int &col],int a,int b) {
         for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                         if(p[i][j].getStat()==closed)cout<<"C ";
                         if(p[i][j].getStat()==secure)cout<<"S ";
                         if(p[i][j].getBomb()==true&&p[i][j].getStat()==open)cout<<"% ";
                         if(p[i][j].getBomb()==false&&p[i][j].getStat()==open) {
                                 if(p[i][j].getNum()==0)cout<<"0 ";
                                 else cout<<p[i][j].getNum()<<" ";
                         }
                 cout<<endl;
                 }
         }
 }

 int main() {
         int row,col,m;
         cout<<"Rows: ";cin>>row;cout<<"Columns: ";cin>>col;
         m=row*col;
         gameCell p[row][col];
         gameConstruct(p[][col],m);
         gameDisplay(p[][col],row,col);
 }
```

I tried this way but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Please give more informations. Usualy the word “Array” is used for C-Style arrays like int b[10]; while in C++ (as you tagged the question) you should use std::vector . How do you declare your array? What did you try so far to passing it to a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you cannot have variable length arrays. That is, you can't take an input integer and use it as the size of an array, like so:

```
std::cin >> x;
int array[x];
```

(This will work in gcc but it is a non-portable extension)

But of course, it is possible to do something similar. The language feature that allows you to have dynamically sized arrays is dynamic allocation with `new[]`. You can do this:

```
std::cin >> x;
int* array = new int[x];
```

But note, `array` here is *not* an array type. It is a pointer type. If you want to dynamically allocate a two dimensional array, you have to do something like so:

```
std::cin >> x >> y;
int** array = new int*[x]; // First allocate an array of pointers
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  array[i] = new int[y]; // Allocate each row of the 2D array
}
```

But again, this is still not an array type. It is now an `int**`, or a "pointer to pointer to int". If you want to pass this to a function, you will need the argument of the function to be `int**`. For example:

```
void func(int**);
func(array);
```

That will be fine. However, you almost always need to know the dimensions of the array inside the function. How can you do that? Just pass them as extra arguments!

```
void func(int**, int, int);
func(array, x, y);
```

This is of course one way to do it, but it's certainly not the idiomatic C++ way to do it. It has problems with safety, because its very easy to forget to `delete` everything. You have to manually manage the memory allocation. You will have to do this to avoid a memory leak:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  delete[] array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

So forget everything I just told you. Make use of the standard library containers. You can easily use `std::vector` and have no concern for passing the dimensions:

```
void func(std::vector<std::vector<int>>);

std::cin >> x >> y;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(x, std::vector<int>(y));
func(vec);
```

---

If you do end up dealing with array types instead of dynamically allocating your arrays, then you can get the dimensions of your array by defining a template function that takes a reference to an array:

```
template <int N, int M>
void func(int (&array)[N][M]);
```

The function will be instantiated for all different sizes of array that are passed to it. The template parameters (dimensions of the array) must be known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I took your advise on vectors and implemented it, I found out that there must be a space here: std::vector<std::vector<int> >. Regardless, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, yes, in C++03 there must be a space. It's not necessary in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun(int tab[][6], int first)
{}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int tab[5][6];
    fun(tab, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

In function definition you must put size of second index. Number of column is passed as argument.

Comment: The problem is that the size of the second index I must input myself, as you can see in the code. I mean the equivalent of your "6". How do I pass the variable "col" instead of "6"?

Comment: @user1563544 You can't, see sftrabbit's answer.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
int* generate2DArray(int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int* array2D = new int[rowSize, colSize];
    return array2D;
}
```

example . . .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int* generate2DArray(int rowSize, int colSize);
int random(int min, int max);

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int row, col;
    cout << "Enter row, then colums:";
    cin >> row >> col;

    //fill array and display
    int *ptr = generate2DArray(row, col);
    for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
        for(int j=0; j<col; ++j)
        {
            ptr[i,j] = random(-50,50);
            printf("[%i][%i]: %i\n", i, j, ptr[i,j]);
        }

    return 0;
}


int* generate2DArray(int rowSize, int colSize)
{
    int* array2D = new int[rowSize, colSize];
    return array2D;
}

int random(int min, int max)
{
    return (rand() % (max+1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from [Problems with 'int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725844/problems-with-int) that you have followed the advices of the validated question and that you are using std::vector

Here is a function that returns the number of columns of an "array" (and 0 if there is a problem).

```
int num_column(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > & data){
    if(data.size() == 0){
        std::cout << "There is no row" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int first_col_size = data[0].size();
    for(auto row : data) {
        if(row.size() != first_col_size){
            std::cout << "All the columns don't have the same size" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return first_col_size;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C-style arrays, you might want to make a reference in the parameter:

```
int (&array)[2][2]; // reference to 2-dimensional array
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of accessing `p[i][j]` you should access `p[i*b + j]` - this is actually what the compiler do for you since `int[a][b]` is flattened in the memory to an array in size of `a*b`

Also, you can change the prototype of the function to "void gameDisplay(gameCell p[],int a,int b)"

The fixed code:

```
void gameDisplay(gameCell p[],int a, int b) {
         for(int i=0;i<a;i++) {
                for(int j=0;j<b;j++) {
                         if(p[i*a +j].getStat()==closed)cout<<"C ";
                         if(p[i*a +j].getStat()==secure)cout<<"S ";
                         if(p[i*a +j].getBomb()==true&&p[i][j].getStat()==open)cout<<"% ";
                         if(p[i*a +j].getBomb()==false&&p[i][j].getStat()==open) {
                                 if(p[i*a +j].getNum()==0)cout<<"0 ";
                                 else cout<<p[i*a +j].getNum()<<" ";
                         }
                 cout<<endl;
                 }
         }
 }

 int main() {
         int row,col,m;
         cout<<"Rows: ";cin>>row;cout<<"Columns: ";cin>>col;
         m=row*col;
         gameCell p[row][col];
         gameConstruct(p[][col],m);
         gameDisplay(p[],row,col);
 }
```